# How to translate a program installed by snap package?

Tags: unity, snap, translation, gettext

I installed VLC  by snap packages in Ubuntu 16.10 Yakkety Yak. But the installation was done in English (my version of Ubuntu is in Spanish)

Basically the same question has been asked at [Snap (snapcraft?) and translated apps](https://askubuntu.com/q/863013) and [How it change language in vlc (snap)](https://askubuntu.com/q/839329), and translation files for VLC are present:

```
$ locate /vlc.mo
/snap/vlc/1/share/locale/ach/LC_MESSAGES/vlc.mo
/snap/vlc/1/share/locale/af/LC_MESSAGES/vlc.mo
/snap/vlc/1/share/locale/am/LC_MESSAGES/vlc.mo
/snap/vlc/1/share/locale/an/LC_MESSAGES/vlc.mo
/snap/vlc/1/share/locale/ar/LC_MESSAGES/vlc.mo
/snap/vlc/1/share/locale/ast/LC_MESSAGES/vlc.mo
/snap/vlc/1/share/locale/az/LC_MESSAGES/vlc.mo
/snap/vlc/1/share/locale/be/LC_MESSAGES/vlc.mo
/snap/vlc/1/share/locale/bg/LC_MESSAGES/vlc.mo
/snap/vlc/1/share/locale/bn/LC_MESSAGES/vlc.mo
/snap/vlc/1/share/locale/bn_IN/LC_MESSAGES/vlc.mo
/snap/vlc/1/share/locale/br/LC_MESSAGES/vlc.mo
/snap/vlc/1/share/locale/bs/LC_MESSAGES/vlc.mo
/snap/vlc/1/share/locale/ca/LC_MESSAGES/vlc.mo
/snap/vlc/1/share/locale/cgg/LC_MESSAGES/vlc.mo
/snap/vlc/1/share/locale/ckb/LC_MESSAGES/vlc.mo
/snap/vlc/1/share/locale/co/LC_MESSAGES/vlc.mo
/snap/vlc/1/share/locale/cs/LC_MESSAGES/vlc.mo
/snap/vlc/1/share/locale/cy/LC_MESSAGES/vlc.mo
/snap/vlc/1/share/locale/da/LC_MESSAGES/vlc.mo
/snap/vlc/1/share/locale/de/LC_MESSAGES/vlc.mo
/snap/vlc/1/share/locale/el/LC_MESSAGES/vlc.mo
/snap/vlc/1/share/locale/en_GB/LC_MESSAGES/vlc.mo
/snap/vlc/1/share/locale/es/LC_MESSAGES/vlc.mo
/snap/vlc/1/share/locale/et/LC_MESSAGES/vlc.mo
/snap/vlc/1/share/locale/eu/LC_MESSAGES/vlc.mo
/snap/vlc/1/share/locale/fa/LC_MESSAGES/vlc.mo
/snap/vlc/1/share/locale/ff/LC_MESSAGES/vlc.mo
/snap/vlc/1/share/locale/fi/LC_MESSAGES/vlc.mo
/snap/vlc/1/share/locale/fr/LC_MESSAGES/vlc.mo
/snap/vlc/1/share/locale/fur/LC_MESSAGES/vlc.mo
/snap/vlc/1/share/locale/ga/LC_MESSAGES/vlc.mo
/snap/vlc/1/share/locale/gd/LC_MESSAGES/vlc.mo
/snap/vlc/1/share/locale/gl/LC_MESSAGES/vlc.mo
/snap/vlc/1/share/locale/gu/LC_MESSAGES/vlc.mo
/snap/vlc/1/share/locale/he/LC_MESSAGES/vlc.mo
/snap/vlc/1/share/locale/hi/LC_MESSAGES/vlc.mo
/snap/vlc/1/share/locale/hr/LC_MESSAGES/vlc.mo
/snap/vlc/1/share/locale/hu/LC_MESSAGES/vlc.mo
/snap/vlc/1/share/locale/hy/LC_MESSAGES/vlc.mo
/snap/vlc/1/share/locale/ia/LC_MESSAGES/vlc.mo
/snap/vlc/1/share/locale/id/LC_MESSAGES/vlc.mo
/snap/vlc/1/share/locale/is/LC_MESSAGES/vlc.mo
/snap/vlc/1/share/locale/it/LC_MESSAGES/vlc.mo
/snap/vlc/1/share/locale/ja/LC_MESSAGES/vlc.mo
/snap/vlc/1/share/locale/ka/LC_MESSAGES/vlc.mo
/snap/vlc/1/share/locale/kk/LC_MESSAGES/vlc.mo
/snap/vlc/1/share/locale/km/LC_MESSAGES/vlc.mo
/snap/vlc/1/share/locale/kn/LC_MESSAGES/vlc.mo
/snap/vlc/1/share/locale/ko/LC_MESSAGES/vlc.mo
/snap/vlc/1/share/locale/ky/LC_MESSAGES/vlc.mo
/snap/vlc/1/share/locale/lg/LC_MESSAGES/vlc.mo
/snap/vlc/1/share/locale/lt/LC_MESSAGES/vlc.mo
/snap/vlc/1/share/locale/lv/LC_MESSAGES/vlc.mo
/snap/vlc/1/share/locale/mk/LC_MESSAGES/vlc.mo
/snap/vlc/1/share/locale/ml/LC_MESSAGES/vlc.mo
/snap/vlc/1/share/locale/mn/LC_MESSAGES/vlc.mo
/snap/vlc/1/share/locale/mr/LC_MESSAGES/vlc.mo
/snap/vlc/1/share/locale/ms/LC_MESSAGES/vlc.mo
/snap/vlc/1/share/locale/my/LC_MESSAGES/vlc.mo
/snap/vlc/1/share/locale/nb/LC_MESSAGES/vlc.mo
/snap/vlc/1/share/locale/ne/LC_MESSAGES/vlc.mo
/snap/vlc/1/share/locale/nl/LC_MESSAGES/vlc.mo
/snap/vlc/1/share/locale/nn/LC_MESSAGES/vlc.mo
/snap/vlc/1/share/locale/oc/LC_MESSAGES/vlc.mo
/snap/vlc/1/share/locale/or/LC_MESSAGES/vlc.mo
/snap/vlc/1/share/locale/pa/LC_MESSAGES/vlc.mo
/snap/vlc/1/share/locale/pl/LC_MESSAGES/vlc.mo
/snap/vlc/1/share/locale/ps/LC_MESSAGES/vlc.mo
/snap/vlc/1/share/locale/pt_BR/LC_MESSAGES/vlc.mo
/snap/vlc/1/share/locale/pt_PT/LC_MESSAGES/vlc.mo
/snap/vlc/1/share/locale/ro/LC_MESSAGES/vlc.mo
/snap/vlc/1/share/locale/ru/LC_MESSAGES/vlc.mo
/snap/vlc/1/share/locale/si/LC_MESSAGES/vlc.mo
/snap/vlc/1/share/locale/sk/LC_MESSAGES/vlc.mo
/snap/vlc/1/share/locale/sl/LC_MESSAGES/vlc.mo
/snap/vlc/1/share/locale/sq/LC_MESSAGES/vlc.mo
/snap/vlc/1/share/locale/sr/LC_MESSAGES/vlc.mo
/snap/vlc/1/share/locale/sv/LC_MESSAGES/vlc.mo
/snap/vlc/1/share/locale/ta/LC_MESSAGES/vlc.mo
/snap/vlc/1/share/locale/te/LC_MESSAGES/vlc.mo
/snap/vlc/1/share/locale/tet/LC_MESSAGES/vlc.mo
/snap/vlc/1/share/locale/th/LC_MESSAGES/vlc.mo
/snap/vlc/1/share/locale/tl/LC_MESSAGES/vlc.mo
/snap/vlc/1/share/locale/tr/LC_MESSAGES/vlc.mo
/snap/vlc/1/share/locale/uk/LC_MESSAGES/vlc.mo
/snap/vlc/1/share/locale/uz/LC_MESSAGES/vlc.mo
/snap/vlc/1/share/locale/vi/LC_MESSAGES/vlc.mo
/snap/vlc/1/share/locale/wa/LC_MESSAGES/vlc.mo
/snap/vlc/1/share/locale/zh_CN/LC_MESSAGES/vlc.mo
/snap/vlc/1/share/locale/zh_TW/LC_MESSAGES/vlc.mo
/snap/vlc/1/share/locale/zu/LC_MESSAGES/vlc.mo
/snap/vlc/1/usr/share/locale/ach/LC_MESSAGES/vlc.mo
/snap/vlc/1/usr/share/locale/af/LC_MESSAGES/vlc.mo
/snap/vlc/1/usr/share/locale/am/LC_MESSAGES/vlc.mo
/snap/vlc/1/usr/share/locale/an/LC_MESSAGES/vlc.mo
/snap/vlc/1/usr/share/locale/ar/LC_MESSAGES/vlc.mo
/snap/vlc/1/usr/share/locale/ast/LC_MESSAGES/vlc.mo
/snap/vlc/1/usr/share/locale/az/LC_MESSAGES/vlc.mo
/snap/vlc/1/usr/share/locale/be/LC_MESSAGES/vlc.mo
/snap/vlc/1/usr/share/locale/bg/LC_MESSAGES/vlc.mo
/snap/vlc/1/usr/share/locale/bn/LC_MESSAGES/vlc.mo
/snap/vlc/1/usr/share/locale/bn_IN/LC_MESSAGES/vlc.mo
/snap/vlc/1/usr/share/locale/br/LC_MESSAGES/vlc.mo
/snap/vlc/1/usr/share/locale/bs/LC_MESSAGES/vlc.mo
/snap/vlc/1/usr/share/locale/ca/LC_MESSAGES/vlc.mo
/snap/vlc/1/usr/share/locale/cgg/LC_MESSAGES/vlc.mo
/snap/vlc/1/usr/share/locale/ckb/LC_MESSAGES/vlc.mo
/snap/vlc/1/usr/share/locale/co/LC_MESSAGES/vlc.mo
/snap/vlc/1/usr/share/locale/cs/LC_MESSAGES/vlc.mo
/snap/vlc/1/usr/share/locale/cy/LC_MESSAGES/vlc.mo
/snap/vlc/1/usr/share/locale/da/LC_MESSAGES/vlc.mo
/snap/vlc/1/usr/share/locale/de/LC_MESSAGES/vlc.mo
/snap/vlc/1/usr/share/locale/el/LC_MESSAGES/vlc.mo
/snap/vlc/1/usr/share/locale/en_GB/LC_MESSAGES/vlc.mo
/snap/vlc/1/usr/share/locale/es/LC_MESSAGES/vlc.mo
/snap/vlc/1/usr/share/locale/es_MX/LC_MESSAGES/vlc.mo
/snap/vlc/1/usr/share/locale/et/LC_MESSAGES/vlc.mo
/snap/vlc/1/usr/share/locale/eu/LC_MESSAGES/vlc.mo
/snap/vlc/1/usr/share/locale/fa/LC_MESSAGES/vlc.mo
/snap/vlc/1/usr/share/locale/ff/LC_MESSAGES/vlc.mo
/snap/vlc/1/usr/share/locale/fi/LC_MESSAGES/vlc.mo
/snap/vlc/1/usr/share/locale/fr/LC_MESSAGES/vlc.mo
/snap/vlc/1/usr/share/locale/fur/LC_MESSAGES/vlc.mo
/snap/vlc/1/usr/share/locale/ga/LC_MESSAGES/vlc.mo
/snap/vlc/1/usr/share/locale/gd/LC_MESSAGES/vlc.mo
/snap/vlc/1/usr/share/locale/gl/LC_MESSAGES/vlc.mo
/snap/vlc/1/usr/share/locale/gu/LC_MESSAGES/vlc.mo
/snap/vlc/1/usr/share/locale/he/LC_MESSAGES/vlc.mo
/snap/vlc/1/usr/share/locale/hi/LC_MESSAGES/vlc.mo
/snap/vlc/1/usr/share/locale/hr/LC_MESSAGES/vlc.mo
/snap/vlc/1/usr/share/locale/hu/LC_MESSAGES/vlc.mo
/snap/vlc/1/usr/share/locale/hy/LC_MESSAGES/vlc.mo
/snap/vlc/1/usr/share/locale/ia/LC_MESSAGES/vlc.mo
/snap/vlc/1/usr/share/locale/id/LC_MESSAGES/vlc.mo
/snap/vlc/1/usr/share/locale/is/LC_MESSAGES/vlc.mo
/snap/vlc/1/usr/share/locale/it/LC_MESSAGES/vlc.mo
/snap/vlc/1/usr/share/locale/ja/LC_MESSAGES/vlc.mo
/snap/vlc/1/usr/share/locale/ka/LC_MESSAGES/vlc.mo
/snap/vlc/1/usr/share/locale/kk/LC_MESSAGES/vlc.mo
/snap/vlc/1/usr/share/locale/km/LC_MESSAGES/vlc.mo
/snap/vlc/1/usr/share/locale/kn/LC_MESSAGES/vlc.mo
/snap/vlc/1/usr/share/locale/ko/LC_MESSAGES/vlc.mo
/snap/vlc/1/usr/share/locale/ks_IN/LC_MESSAGES/vlc.mo
/snap/vlc/1/usr/share/locale/ky/LC_MESSAGES/vlc.mo
/snap/vlc/1/usr/share/locale/lg/LC_MESSAGES/vlc.mo
/snap/vlc/1/usr/share/locale/lt/LC_MESSAGES/vlc.mo
/snap/vlc/1/usr/share/locale/lv/LC_MESSAGES/vlc.mo
/snap/vlc/1/usr/share/locale/mai/LC_MESSAGES/vlc.mo
/snap/vlc/1/usr/share/locale/mk/LC_MESSAGES/vlc.mo
/snap/vlc/1/usr/share/locale/ml/LC_MESSAGES/vlc.mo
/snap/vlc/1/usr/share/locale/mn/LC_MESSAGES/vlc.mo
/snap/vlc/1/usr/share/locale/mr/LC_MESSAGES/vlc.mo
/snap/vlc/1/usr/share/locale/ms/LC_MESSAGES/vlc.mo
/snap/vlc/1/usr/share/locale/my/LC_MESSAGES/vlc.mo
/snap/vlc/1/usr/share/locale/nb/LC_MESSAGES/vlc.mo
/snap/vlc/1/usr/share/locale/ne/LC_MESSAGES/vlc.mo
/snap/vlc/1/usr/share/locale/nl/LC_MESSAGES/vlc.mo
/snap/vlc/1/usr/share/locale/nn/LC_MESSAGES/vlc.mo
/snap/vlc/1/usr/share/locale/oc/LC_MESSAGES/vlc.mo
/snap/vlc/1/usr/share/locale/or/LC_MESSAGES/vlc.mo
/snap/vlc/1/usr/share/locale/pa/LC_MESSAGES/vlc.mo
/snap/vlc/1/usr/share/locale/pl/LC_MESSAGES/vlc.mo
/snap/vlc/1/usr/share/locale/ps/LC_MESSAGES/vlc.mo
/snap/vlc/1/usr/share/locale/pt_BR/LC_MESSAGES/vlc.mo
/snap/vlc/1/usr/share/locale/pt_PT/LC_MESSAGES/vlc.mo
/snap/vlc/1/usr/share/locale/ro/LC_MESSAGES/vlc.mo
/snap/vlc/1/usr/share/locale/ru/LC_MESSAGES/vlc.mo
/snap/vlc/1/usr/share/locale/si/LC_MESSAGES/vlc.mo
/snap/vlc/1/usr/share/locale/sk/LC_MESSAGES/vlc.mo
/snap/vlc/1/usr/share/locale/sl/LC_MESSAGES/vlc.mo
/snap/vlc/1/usr/share/locale/sq/LC_MESSAGES/vlc.mo
/snap/vlc/1/usr/share/locale/sr/LC_MESSAGES/vlc.mo
/snap/vlc/1/usr/share/locale/sv/LC_MESSAGES/vlc.mo
/snap/vlc/1/usr/share/locale/ta/LC_MESSAGES/vlc.mo
/snap/vlc/1/usr/share/locale/te/LC_MESSAGES/vlc.mo
/snap/vlc/1/usr/share/locale/tet/LC_MESSAGES/vlc.mo
/snap/vlc/1/usr/share/locale/th/LC_MESSAGES/vlc.mo
/snap/vlc/1/usr/share/locale/tl/LC_MESSAGES/vlc.mo
/snap/vlc/1/usr/share/locale/tr/LC_MESSAGES/vlc.mo
/snap/vlc/1/usr/share/locale/uk/LC_MESSAGES/vlc.mo
/snap/vlc/1/usr/share/locale/uz/LC_MESSAGES/vlc.mo
/snap/vlc/1/usr/share/locale/vi/LC_MESSAGES/vlc.mo
/snap/vlc/1/usr/share/locale/wa/LC_MESSAGES/vlc.mo
/snap/vlc/1/usr/share/locale/zh_CN/LC_MESSAGES/vlc.mo
/snap/vlc/1/usr/share/locale/zh_TW/LC_MESSAGES/vlc.mo
/snap/vlc/1/usr/share/locale/zu/LC_MESSAGES/vlc.mo
```

Answer (score 3):

For applications packaged as snaps, it may be necessary to make a change to the code so that it can find the translations in the correct location in the file system.

For applications and libraries which use gettext, this means that the call to `bindtextdomain()` needs to prepend the value of the `$SNAP` environment variable to the directory path passed in as the second argument. Any applications (and/or libraries they may be using) which don't do this, may indeed not have working translations, due to the hard-coded path being used pointing at a path outside of the snap.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Probably this is a packaging issue then, and I sent a [message to the snapcraft mailing list](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/snapcraft/2016-December/002150.html).

Answer (score 2):

As [ToX 82](https://askubuntu.com/users/411578/tox-82) pointed out in a comment at [Snap (snapcraft?) and translated apps](https://askubuntu.com/q/863013), there is a [bug report](https://launchpad.net/bugs/1576282). This seems not to be an issue with the individual VLC snap, after all, but rather a general snap localization issue.

Comment: There are multiple possible ways to "solve" it, including possibly patching gettext/libintl itself to always prepend the $SNAP value in bindtextdomain(), but really things packaged as snaps should be built to refer to necessary files inside the snap via relative paths.

Comment: @dobey: Ok, so you mean that irrespective of that overall discussion, it will work if you do 'the right thing' when building a snap?

Comment: Yes, generally. There may be issues in underlying libraries that get pulled in, but if everything is contained in the snap and the binaries are built to refer to paths in the snap, it will work.