# How it change language in vlc (snap)

Tags: vlc, snap, 16.10

my laptop has Ubuntu 16.10, with Spanish default language. I installed vlc by snap (to have the latest version 3.0). VLC works with the English language, how you can change the language ?, for more I look I find no option.